# How to handle exception in the insert code using ASP.NET?

Tags: asp.net, sql

I have a table in SQL Server Management Express named "Table_1". I have successfully connected my ASP program with the Database. I have coded the following coding for inserting data in the database.

```
    using System;
    using System.Collections;
    using System.Configuration;
    using System.Data;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Web;
    using System.Web.Security;
    using System.Web.UI;
    using System.Web.UI.HtmlControls;
    using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
    using System.Web.UI.WebControls.WebParts;
    using System.Xml.Linq;
    using System.Data.SqlClient;
    namespace k2
    {
    public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
    SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("Data Source=ARTHY/SQLEXPRESS;Initial                  Catalog=k2;Integrated Security=True");
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {           
    }
    protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
    try
    {
    conn.Open();          
    }
    catch
    {
    SqlCommand hi = new SqlCommand("insert into Table_1 values('" + TextBox1.Text +    "','" + TextBox2.Text + "','" + TextBox3.Text + "','" + TextBox4.Text + "','" + TextBox5.Text + "','" + TextBox6.Text + "'),conn");
    hi.ExecuteNonQuery();
    conn.Close();
    }    
    }
    }
    }
```

When I am trying to insert any data, I got an exception as follows:

```
    ExecuteNonQuery: Connection property has not been initialized.
    Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web     request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it  originated in the code. 
    Exception Details: System.InvalidOperationException: ExecuteNonQuery: Connection  property has not been initialized.
    Source Error: 
    Line 34:             {
    Line 35:                 SqlCommand hi = new SqlCommand("insert into Table_1 values('" + TextBox1.Text + "','" + TextBox2.Text + "','" + TextBox3.Text + "','" +  TextBox4.Text + "','" + TextBox5.Text + "','" + TextBox6.Text + "'),conn");
    Line 36:                 hi.ExecuteNonQuery();
    Line 37:                 conn.Close();
    Line 38:             }
```

Please, help me with an idea to clear the exception.

Comment: First, Why is this code in the catch block while it should be after the `conn.Open()`?

Comment: I have just tried to clear exception. Before I give the try and catch block, the exception is on "conn.Open();". Then after implementing try and catch, it moved on to "hi.ExecuteNonQuery();".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `conn.Open()` line is in the `try{}` block while the rest of your code is in the `catch{}` block.  So, the `conn.Open()` line is throwing an exception, triggering the `catch{}` which now has no `conn` reference.  Move your code around:

```
try
{
  conn.Open();          
  SqlCommand hi = new SqlCommand("insert into Table_1 values('" + TextBox1.Text +    "','" + TextBox2.Text + "','" + TextBox3.Text + "','" + TextBox4.Text + "','" + TextBox5.Text + "','" + TextBox6.Text + "')", conn);
  hi.ExecuteNonQuery();
  conn.Close();
}
catch
{
  //do something else if there is an exception
}
```

Comment: Now, Exception was cleared. But, the data is not inserted in the database. There was no error or exception but also no data is inserted in the database.

Comment: Whoops, just noticed the ", conn" at the end of the SqlCommand line was in quotes - it should not have been.

Comment: Yes, I have tried that, but only same result.I have changed like this: SqlCommand hi = new SqlCommand("insert into Table_1 values('" + TextBox1.Text +    "','" + TextBox2.Text + "','" + TextBox3.Text + "','" + TextBox4.Text + "','" + TextBox5.Text + "','" + TextBox6.Text + "')", conn);

Comment: Change your catch line to catch(Exception ex) { throw ex; } to see what the real exception is...

Comment: A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: Named Pipes Provider, error: 40 - Could not open a connection to SQL Server)--------------->> This is the Exception I got.

Comment: Then you need to ensure you can reach the database with the info in your connection string.  Is 'ARTHY/SQLEXPRESS' accessible via SSMS?

Comment: Yes, I can able to get connection with SQL SERVER. I am assuring this because I can able to  open and view the table through server explorer in ASP.

Comment: Well, your code can't get to the Sql Server.  Perhaps it's an authentication issue - your connection string is using integrated security.  Check this or perhaps use sql user/pass instead.

Comment: Yes, I have got cleared of this problem. Thanks for your help and time.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to Matt's answer I'd suggest wrapping connection into using statement to make sure the connection is always closed properly. Here is my implementation (refactored a little bit)

```
try
{
    using (var connection = new SqlConnection("Data Source=ARTHY/SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=k2;Integrated Security=True"))
    {
        connection.Open();
        var commandText = string.Format("insert into Table_1 values('{0}','{1}','{2}','{3}','{4}','{5}')",
                                        TextBox1.Text,
                                        TextBox2.Text,
                                        TextBox3.Text,
                                        TextBox4.Text,
                                        TextBox5.Text,
                                        TextBox6.Text);

        var command = new SqlCommand(commandText, connection);
        command.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
}
catch (Exception exception)
{
    // do something with exception
}
```

Comment: BTW, consider using SqlParameters to avoid SQL injections

Comment: Just noticed that I forgot to open connection before executing a command. Fixed.